# is this a bug in php DateTime?

Tags: php, datetime

As the title says, is this a bug in dateTime or something i have done

The below code worked fine until today (2015/01/**31**)

```
$amountMonths = 11; // amount of months (inc 0)
$labels_arr = array(); // label array
$points_arr = array(); // points array

for ($interval = 0; $interval <= $amountMonths; $interval++) {
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->sub(new DateInterval('P'.$interval.'M'));
    $labels_arr[] = $date->format('M Y');
    $points_arr[] = $payments_obj->getMonthlyPaymentTotalByDate($date->format('n'), $date->format('Y'));
}
```

The dates that are been returned today are:

```
Jan 15, Dec 14, Dec 14, Oct 14, Oct 14, Aug 14, Jul 14, Jul 14, May 14, may 14, Mar 14, Mar 14
```

As mentioned before, until today all worked well and returned the past 12 months. No code has been changed but today the wrong dates are being returned.

FYI: the line (below and above) is just a query by month and year, and is returning the correct results, but the dates been added by php are wrong

```
$payments_obj->getMonthlyPaymentTotalByDate($date->format('n'), $date->format('Y'));
```

I can not work out why? is it a bug or something i have done or a possible server config

Comment: And why do you think it's a bug? What is not expected in it?

Comment: The PHP reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php) (see example #3) refers to a problem with subtracting months but doesn't explain it. This behaviour seems to be contrary to expectations, but apparently by design

Comment: @HoboSapiens "This behaviour seems to be contrary to expectations" --- what day is `January 31st + 1 month`? What day is `Jan 31 + 1 month + 1 day`? What day is `Jan 31 + 1 day + 1 month`?

Comment: @zerkms i get the current date and time correct (GMT) of 2015-01-31 20:56:43

Comment: @Ford okay, your current time is correct. Check my comment above to HoboSapiens

Comment: @zerkms Jan 31st + 1 Month returns 2015-03-03 20:59:47

Comment: Just as a note, I tried $date->sub(new DateInterval('P' . $interval . 'M')); on my own computer. When $interval is 1, the returned date is 31st of December 2014. When $interval is 2, the date is 1st of December 2014. When $interval is 3, the returned date is 31st of October.

Comment: @Ford I did not ask what it will return (I obviously can run it myself). I am asking what you expect it to be.

Comment: @zerkms i know i get the current date correct (so maybe not a bug here) but when add or sub 1 month i get the wrong date

Comment: @Ford it's not wrong. It's your expectations that are wrong. That's why I asked what you would expect for those calculations.

Comment: @TheNavigator this is what i get too :-(

Comment: @zerkms sorry if i did not read your comment correct, i was trying tests and trying to reply to all too.... i would expect the results to return the previous or next month, not just add 30/31 days to the date (as it appears to do). i would think this is what "add/sub days" is for... this is highly likely to be my misunderstanding though..... :-(  maybe i will try another method.....

Comment: @Ford well, I'll try the last time: what do you expect for `Jan 31 + 1 month`? And for `Jan 31 + 1 month - 1 month`? "the results to return the previous or next month" --- why don't you take the day that exists in every month? Like the 1st?